# Create FileGDB using Geoprocessor on ArcGIS 10.3 ArcObject

Tags: arcobjects, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, geoprocessing

Exact same code working fine with 10.0. But, 10.3 usual Esri "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component".

```
                Geoprocessor geoprocessor = new Geoprocessor();

                //create fGDB
                CreateFileGDB createFileGDB = new CreateFileGDB();
                createFileGDB.out_folder_path = path;
                createFileGDB.out_name = name;
                createFileGDB.out_version = "10.3";
```

Comment: Instead of "10.3" in out_version perhaps try "CURRENT" to match the currently installed version. I assume somewhere in the next few lines you're using the geoprocessor to run the createfilegdb.. is this Java or .net API? they look very similar but this is following the Java syntax.. just wanted to make sure you're using the right examples. E_FAIL doesn't mean much, just that an unspecified error has occured, check that path exists and that appropriate permissions exist.

Comment: Thanks. "CURRENT" works. Just to add more info, I also need to have advanced license instantiated error also happened when only using engine license.

Comment: Is that Server Advanced? It's quite possible that with Basic Server licensing you can't perform this operation... you would need at least a Server Standard (for workgroup or enterprise) to perform any kind of geoprocessing.

Comment: I used desktop advanced. My app is running from workstation.